Use of colon and other symbols in citation
I'm currently working on a uni assignment regarding a piece of academic work, but I'm confused about some of the punctuation and symbols used in citations. 1) Consider this extract: "“phenomena of translating and translation(s) as they manifest themselves in the world of our experience” (Holmes 1988: 71)". I did some search on this aspect, but I'm still unsure. Does 71 means page 71 of that issue in this case or is it something else? 2) It could be a typo, since I couldn't find any info on that, but perhaps it does have some meaning behind it. Consider this: "Appropriateness for the purpose in a given context is described by norms and conventions which operate in a culture. Reiss and Vermeer (1991: 178f) prefer to speak of conventions instead of norms...". What could "f" beside the number 178 stand for? Thank you in advance for the answer!
P.S. I'm sorry if question like that has already been answered somewhere, I really  couldn't find exactly this question asked and answered. Also, I apologise for any mistakes, I'm not a native speaker

I would consider what comes after those colons to be page numbers. The use of ‘f’ usually means ‘and following’ - so not just page 178 but ongoing for at least one page more.

Some citation styles use(d) colons before the page number in parenthetical citations, so 71 being a page number is indeed the right interpretation. This becomes especially clear upon googling the sentences you quote, as the corresponding entry in the reference list is

Holmes, James S. 1988. “The name and nature of Translation Studies.” In Translated!: Papers on Literary Translation and Translation Studies, James S. Holmes; with an introduction by Raymond van den Broeck, 67–80. Amsterdam: Rodopi.

which looks like a book chapter with a page range that includes p. 71.
In the second citation, the letter "f" stands for the Latin word folio, which is typically interpreted as "and the following page(s)" Sometimes the intent refers to some other "components" of the cited work, e.g. paragraphs, verses, etc. (The potential ambiguity is typically resolved when reading the cited work.) This format is somewhat outdated, and best avoided in your own writing.

Specifically, "p. 71f" typically means "page 71 and the following page", and "p. 71ff" would mean "page 71 and following pages". The convention of adding "f" and "ff" is fairly widely used in German writing, for example.

@WolfgangBangerth I think you're right for sources that use both "f" and "ff", but I think I have also seen sources that never used "ff" but were on occasion clearly referencing several pages.
